# How to get fast help on a "UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION" Exception

Tags: support

This has happened twice to me in the past 6 months. A SOQL query started throwing a UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION exception (at a customer site). Both times the interaction with support went something like:

- it must be the application's fault
- we gave support the query that failed (the query must be too complex [though it returned the wrong error for this case)
- we gave support the SOAP request/response envelopes
- we gave support a tiny query that failed.

In a case from today, the final query that failed was:

```
SELECT Id,Is_Case_Management__c FROM Case   LIMIT 1
```

In fact, we discovered that any query on Case that includes this column fails with an UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION exception.

Now that we have narrowed it down to something so simple I have hopes that the issue will be addressed. The cost is a couple of frustrating weeks for one of Salesforce's larger customers.  What is a mechanism that works for more quickly bringing this type of issue to a resolution.

Comment: for your commiseration amusement see http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/2084/2602